# Unable to require component conditionally inside another

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to `require()` (and render) one of the two components contingent to the value returned by a prop (`lang`). So, if `props.lang` is `spanish`, it should import and render a component named `<Spain />`, otherwise, `<UnitedStates />`:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: 0,
  },
});

const FlagButton = (props) => {
  const {
    lang, classes, ip
  } = props;

  let Flag;

  if(lang === 'spanish') {
    Flag = require('./svg-icons/flags/Spain');
  } else {
    Flag = require('./svg-icons/flags/UnitedStates');
  }

  return (
    <IconButton disableFocusRipple disableRipple className={classes.root}><Flag /></IconButton>
  );
};

FlagButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    root: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ip: state.ip,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(withStyles(styles)(FlagButton));
```

However, this throws the following `invariant violation` error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

What's the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to?

**Additional info**: The files I'm `require()`-ing are valid React components and of the following structure (abridged for brevity):

```
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';

export default function() {
  return (
    <SvgIcon
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      enableBackground="new 0 0 512.001 512.001"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 512.001 512.001"
      xmlSpace="preserve"
    >
      <path
        fill="#F5F5F5"
        d="M503.172 423.725H8.828A8.829 8.829 0 010 414.897V97.104a8.829 8.829 0 018.828-8.828h494.345a8.829 8.829 0 018.828 8.828v317.793a8.83 8.83 0 01-8.829 8.828z"
      />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

**NOTE**: I do **NOT** want to import all components and then render them conditionally. I want to **ONLY** import what I need to render.

Comment: this is `/svg-icons/flags/Spain` js file? and implements icon? otherwise `<Flag />` won't work

Comment: Yes. If I just `import Spain from './svg-icons/flags/Spain';` and then render `<Spain />`, it works without hiccups. But I need to make it dynamic depending on `props.lang`'s value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you experience is probably caused by the differences between "import" and "require".

If your `flags/XXX` components use `export default ...` and you want to import using `require`, then you must explicitly declare the `default` symbol.

Long story short, try:

```
const SpanishFlag = require('./svg-icons/flags/Spain').default;
const USFlag = require('./svg-icons/flags/UnitedStates').default;
```

or even simpler:

```
import SpahishFlag from './svg-icons/flags/Spain'
```

If your intention is to load **only** the flag that you need, this is not the way.  You may want to look into [code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) :-)

Comment: The following worked:
`
if(lang === 'english') {
    Flag = require('./svg-icons/flags/UnitedStates').default;
  } else if(lang === 'spanish') {
    Flag = require('./svg-icons/flags/Mexico').default;
  }
`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do, for example:

```
const SpanishFlag = require('./svg-icons/flags/Spain');
const USFlag = require('./svg-icons/flags/UnitedStates');
```

and then, use a ternary operator inside your IconButton:

```
<IconButton disableFocusRipple disableRipple className={classes.root}>{ lang === 'spanish' ? SpanishFlag : USFlag}</IconButton>
```

Comment: Because that would mean importing unnecessary files which I want to avoid. I only want to import/require what's needed. Performance.

Comment: There's many more components. I've listed two only for illustration. :)